# Visual Studio Class Diagram creator cannot show association c++

Tags: visual-studio-2012, uml

When I try to show a member variable as an association in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, I get the error:

Cannot show as association because 'ServerNetwork*' cannot be found:
Try one of the following:
-Ensure that 'ServerNetwork*' is an existing type.
-If 'ServerNetwork*' is defined outside your project ensure you have placed the correct references in Solution Explorer.

My code compiles and runs so I'm sure ServerNetwork* is a type and it is referenced in the Solution Explorer.

I think it has something to do with ServerNetwork.hpp and ServerNetwork.cpp not being correctly included in the Project because I also have ClientNetwork.hpp and ClientNetwork.cpp which both show fine on the Class Diagram.

Comment: Maybe it's just a bug of the reverse engineering? It seems to see "ServerNetwork*" as class name instead of just "ServerNetwork". Maybe a workaround could be to put a space between ServerNetwork and the * at the field declaration?

Comment: There is a space  between the type and the '*' in my declaration.